# adding class to ckeditor

Tags: styles, drupal-7, ckeditor

I am trying to add a class to a ul using ckeditor in drupal

In ckeditor.styles.js

this works

```
 { name : 'my style', element : 'h1', attributes : { 'class' : 'bigblue' } },
```

this does not

```
 { name : 'my list style', element : 'ul', attributes : { 'class' : 'highlight' } },
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I **WAS** facing the same problem.

Actually, for such styles, you need to create your UL tags with the CkEditor, select it, then it will appear in the style combo, because it is somehow contextual.

Hope this helps.